# Add Link to right click in CKEditor

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor

It would be nice to add Link option in the right click menu on CKEditor.  Currently I have the auto grow plugin enabled. If I have a very long article, I have to highlight the word, scroll up and press link.  It would be nice if we can just handle that in the right click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the [CKEditor Context Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_context_link) module that does just this.